# Handle resignation properly when reporting to two managers

Tags: professionalism, resignation

At my workplace, the organization is based on 2 levels: on-site, and company as a whole.

This situation involves me, manager Bob and manager Steve.

If we take into account the global employee structure, I report to Steve. Bob also reports to Steve, and at least on paper me and Bob are on equal level.
However, according to on-site organization, Bob is a site-level manager of my department and I am reporting to him.

Steve handles my performance reviews, has a final say on my project assignments, signes my holiday forms etc.
Bob handles every day task assignments, has the authority (from Steve) to sign my flex-time or short time-off, has a say in what i'm supposed to do (although he can be overriden by Steve).

Now, I received an offer to work elsewhere and so I will be handing in my resignation. **Who do I hand it to so that I won't cause any misunderstandings?** Do I set up a meeting with Steve, Bob, both of them, at the same time, or separately?

I don't want to cause any feelings of "why wasn't I informed first?" or "why did you inform X without my authorization?".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Who do I hand it to so that I won't cause any misunderstandings?

In this scenario, I would **email them both**.  This way they get the notification pretty much *at the same time*.

> Do I set up a meeting with Steve, Bob, both of them, at the same time,
>   or separately?

After you send the resignation email, I would then follow up with each of them independently and see if they wish to discuss any of the particulars of your departure.  ( Primary knowledge transfer and the like )

Probably goes without saying, but do your best to make your departure as painless as possible.  You never know when you may need a reference, or even return to the company once again.

Comment: My problem with this is that I wouldn't ever consider resigning via email unless your boss is at a different location, even with only one manager. I think it's much more respectful to have that conversation in person first rather than have them get a surprise in their inbox.

Answer (score 2):

It is respectful both to share your decision to leave in person, and to do it in a timely manner once you are in a position to do so (where you would be OK in case they reject your notice period and have you leave right away).

If both Bob and Steve will be on-site shortly, meeting with both of them at the same time is best.  If Steve is not available within a couple of days of when you are ready to resign, meet with Bob in person and let Bob know you will email Steve.  That way both your bosses hear directly from you, and at least the one you have in-person contact with regularly will hear it in person.

Answer (score -3):

You can always send a registered later to the company's official address. If you do that, then the company has legally received notice. If they don't read their mail, that's not your problem.